# How do I write a get request for the user that I have added using Post request on reqres server?

Tags: postman

In the first picture I have created a post request.

[image: Post request]

In the second picture I am creating a get request to find the user I have created in the first step.

[image]

Can someone guide me how do I get the same user that I have posted on reqres server.

Answer (score 0):

It would be:

```
https://reqres.in/api/users/<id>
```

The examples of the calls can be found on the site - https://reqres.in/

The service doesnt store the data that you send it so it's just echoing something back rather that putting it in a database.

It has a static number of users that will be returned in the `GET users` call. That call returns meta data in the response with the number of users and the ids that can be used in the URL path.

> It might seem pretty weird to be sending your data to a 3rd party API, but I can assure you, Reqres does not store any of your data at all. Once you send it to us, we just send it straight back...and then it's gone!

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't seem to work, my post request returns the following {
    "name": "RAK",
    "job": "Automation testing",
    "id": "959",
    "createdAt": "2020-06-25T20:10:03.708Z"
}.              This is my get request ...https://reqres.in/api/users/959   this return empty json {}

Comment: post request is https://reqres.in/api/users with this data in body {
    "name": "RAK",
    "job": "Automation testing"
}

Comment: I don't think that service works in that way, it will allow you to create new users but I think that it only has 12 users available. You can see how many by sending a request to `/api/users` the meta data in the response will tell you the total number of users.